# Why does moving view matrix vertically move my circle vertically, but not horizontally and how to I make it not move at all?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glm-math

I have a game engine I am working on. Right now, I am trying to render circles. I write vertex data to it using the following format:

```
    0       1       2 3 4 5 6         7
v = xOffset yOffset r g b a ssboIndex r
```

These are my shaders:

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 450 core

layout(location = 0) uniform mat4 uProjectionView;
layout(location = 1) uniform vec2 uViewDimensions;
layout(location = 2) uniform mat4 uProjection;
layout(location = 3) uniform mat4 uView;

layout(std430, binding = 3) buffer shaderStorageBuffer {
    mat4 transform[];
};

layout(location = 0) in vec2 positionOffset;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;
layout(location = 2) in float ssboID;
layout(location = 3) in float radius;

out vec2 vertexVPositionOffset;
out vec4 vertexVColor;
out unsigned int vertexVSSBOID;
out float vertexVRadius;

void main() {
    vertexVPositionOffset = positionOffset;
    vertexVColor = color;
    vertexVSSBOID = int(ssboID);
    vertexVRadius = radius;

    // vertexVNormalizedCenter = (uProjectionView * transform[int(ssboID)] * vec4(positionOffset, 0, 1)).xy;
    // vertexVNormalizedRadius = (uProjectionView * vec4(radius, radius, 0, 0)).xy;
}
```

**Geometry Shader**

```
#version 450 core

layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 5) out;

layout(location = 0) uniform mat4 uProjectionView;
layout(location = 1) uniform vec2 uViewDimensions;
layout(location = 2) uniform mat4 uProjection;
layout(location = 3) uniform mat4 uView;

layout(std430, binding = 3) buffer shaderStorageBuffer {
    mat4 transform[];
};

in vec2 vertexVPositionOffset[];
in vec4 vertexVColor[];
in unsigned int vertexVSSBOID[];
in float vertexVRadius[];

out vec4 geometryVColor;
out float geometryVRadius;
out vec2 geometryVCenter;

void main() {
    geometryVRadius = vertexVRadius[0];
    geometryVCenter = (transform[int(vertexVSSBOID[0])] * vec4(vertexVPositionOffset[0], 0, 1)).xy;
    geometryVColor = vertexVColor[0];

    vec2 position;

    position = (uProjectionView * transform[int(vertexVSSBOID[0])] * vec4(vertexVPositionOffset[0].x - geometryVRadius, vertexVPositionOffset[0].y - geometryVRadius, 0, 1)).xy;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
    EmitVertex();

    position = (uProjectionView * transform[int(vertexVSSBOID[0])] * vec4(vertexVPositionOffset[0].x + geometryVRadius, vertexVPositionOffset[0].y - geometryVRadius, 0, 1)).xy;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
    EmitVertex();

    position = (uProjectionView * transform[int(vertexVSSBOID[0])] * vec4(vertexVPositionOffset[0].x + geometryVRadius, vertexVPositionOffset[0].y + geometryVRadius, 0, 1)).xy;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
    EmitVertex();

    position = (uProjectionView * transform[int(vertexVSSBOID[0])] * vec4(vertexVPositionOffset[0].x - geometryVRadius, vertexVPositionOffset[0].y + geometryVRadius, 0, 1)).xy;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
    EmitVertex();

    position = (uProjectionView * transform[int(vertexVSSBOID[0])] * vec4(vertexVPositionOffset[0].x - geometryVRadius, vertexVPositionOffset[0].y - geometryVRadius, 0, 1)).xy;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 450 core

layout(location = 0) uniform mat4 uProjectionView;
layout(location = 1) uniform vec2 uViewDimensions;
layout(location = 2) uniform mat4 uProjection;
layout(location = 3) uniform mat4 uView;

layout(std430, binding = 3) buffer shaderStorageBuffer {
    mat4 transform[];
};

in vec4 geometryVColor;
in float geometryVRadius;
in vec2 geometryVCenter;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main() {
    // vec4 pixelInWorldCoordinate = inverse(uProjection) * vec4(gl_FragCoord.x / (uViewDimensions.x / 2.0f) - 1, 1 - gl_FragCoord.y / (uViewDimensions.y / 2.0f), 0, 1);
    vec4 view = vec4(gl_FragCoord.x / (uViewDimensions.x / 2.0f) - 1, 1 - gl_FragCoord.y / (uViewDimensions.y / 2.0f), 0, 1);
    vec4 pixelInWorldCoordinate = inverse(uProjectionView) * view;
    
    // float d = sqrt(pow(pixelInWorldCoordinate.x - geometryVCenter.x, 2) + pow(-pixelInWorldCoordinate.y - geometryVCenter.y, 2));
    // if (d < geometryVRadius)
    //  color = geometryVColor;
    // else
    //  discard;
    
    float leftExpression = pow(pixelInWorldCoordinate.x - geometryVCenter.x, 2) + pow(pixelInWorldCoordinate.y + geometryVCenter.y, 2);
    float rightExpression = pow(geometryVRadius, 2);
    if (leftExpression <= rightExpression)
        color = geometryVColor;
    else
        discard;
}
```

This is how it looks like without moving the camera:
[image]
Now, if I move the camera vertically, this happens:
[image]
But everything is fine if the camera moves horizontally:
[image]
Why is this happening? I have spent countless hours trying to fix this with no success.

Note: the white square rendered in the background is a reference square being rendered separately. It matches the vertex positions of the circle.
I can add more context if needed.

More context:
Projection matrix is being generated with glortho.
View matrix is an identity matrix to represent the camera translation and is multiplied by projection matrix.
View dimensions are the width and height of the window.
In the fragment shader, I am converting the fragment coordinate to world coordinate to see if the fragment is inside the circle to decide whether or not it needs to be rendered.
Also, moving the circle's transformation matrix does not have any problem. It only happens when I move the camera vertically.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to draw a circular sprite instead of programming a shader to do it? Then you could do anti-aliasing.

Comment: In this case no, because I want to implement as much features as I can without loading any resources such as sprites, image files, sound files, etc.

Comment: To me, this looks like you forgot that in GL, the window space (and hence `gl_FragCoord`) origin is at _bottom_ left.

Comment: YOU ARE SO RIGHT!!! Thank you very much. I spent days now trying to figure this bug out and double guessing all my work. Truth be told, this is the first time I use gl_FragCoord. There were times I thought it was that, but never really could pin the reason why because it was returning the right x value. You should post your reply as an answer and I will happily up vote it.

Comment: When I subtracted uViewDimensions.y with gl_FragCoord.y, I also had to fix the circle formula because I had edited it the circle formula to y + h to sort of fix the rendering of it. Everything works fine now. Thank you.

Comment: To be sure, you can programmatically fill your textures without loading any resources, might be faster then calculating every frame, (this will not matter much it's not gpu-limited), but OT.